# Drawing pixels in C: OSdev

Tags: c, osdev, vga

I’m totally beginner in osdeving. for now i’ve just implemented keyboard and vga screen following the osdevwiki. Now i’d like to draw proper pixel like this

```
void drawPixel(int x, int y, int rgb)
```

in freestanding C language.
now, in vga mode the address for printing text and colors is 0xB8000. To paint pixels in the screen how can i do? i don’t have any clue.

Comment: What do you name VGA mode? 80x25 text? In that mode (which has the buffer at 0xB8000) you can't do any graphics (besides redefining the pixels associated to characters by reprogramming the character generator): it is a text mode. If you want actual graphics (e.g. 640x480x4bit standard VGA, or 800x600x8bit VESA, or...), you first have to enter the proper graphics mode, then to write in the right place in memory (typically 0xA000 for 640x480 VGA mode, but that mode has a weird memory model divided in planes that you have to select...). Some info: https://wiki.osdev.org/Drawing_In_Protected_Mode

Answer (score 3):

Text mode is discussed here:

https://wiki.osdev.org/Text_mode

It has an example here to write a colored character in text mode:

```
void WriteCharacter(unsigned char c, unsigned char forecolour, unsigned char backcolour, int x, int y)
{
     uint16_t attrib = (backcolour << 4) | (forecolour & 0x0F);
     volatile uint16_t * where;
     where = (volatile uint16_t *)0xB8000 + (y * 80 + x) ;
     *where = c | (attrib << 8);
}
```

If you want to write an RGB pixel in graphics mode you have to switch to a different video mode first.

That is explained here:

https://wiki.osdev.org/Drawing_In_Protected_Mode

Here is the code from that page on how to draw a pixel in graphics mode:

```
/* only valid for 800x600x16M */
static void putpixel(unsigned char* screen, int x,int y, int color) {
    unsigned where = x*3 + y*2400;
    screen[where] = color & 255;              // BLUE
    screen[where + 1] = (color >> 8) & 255;   // GREEN
    screen[where + 2] = (color >> 16) & 255;  // RED
}

/* only valid for 800x600x32bpp */
static void putpixel(unsigned char* screen, int x,int y, int color) {
    unsigned where = x*4 + y*3200;
    screen[where] = color & 255;              // BLUE
    screen[where + 1] = (color >> 8) & 255;   // GREEN
    screen[where + 2] = (color >> 16) & 255;  // RED
}
```

Basically you need to write the three color values to three bytes starting from the video memory and offset by the coordinates multiplied by some values to get to the right line and column.

The values are different for the different video modes.

Be aware that even the video memory address is different for VGA/CGA/EGA modes!

Comment: awesome! but as the screen parameter what value should i set? i mean it says that those functions works only in 800x600x16M  and to use it i have to give it a certain ram address.. which? is there a best?

Comment: You have to switch to the right video mode first. Please carefully read the pages I have linked to.

Comment: deeply readed. i'm feeling a bit dumb.. to switch mode i have to use int $0x10 but it crushes the OS

Comment: before the int i've setted al to 0x13 and ah to 0x00

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to draw pixels from text mode. 
Set the character to a space character and use the color as the color of the pixel     eg.

```
   char* video  = (char*)0xb8000;
   video [0] = 0x20; // space character
   video [1] = 0x12; // color of the pixel
```

Comment: Well technically you are not drawing pixels here, but rather ASCII art. I suppose that's fine for low res graphics though.